# Всем привет ,не могли бы подсказать где ошибка и почему не проходит тест?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять по какой причине мой код не проходит тест.

Ниже прикреплю сам код и результаты теста

```js
class World {

  constructor() {

  }

  createPowerPlant() {
    let powerPlant = new PowerPlant();

    return powerPlant;
  }

  createHousehold() {
    let household = new Household();

    return household;
  }

  connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household, powerPlant) {
    household.connecting(powerPlant.connectFromPowerPlant());
  }

  connectHouseholdToHousehold(household1, household2) {

  }

  disconnectHouseholdFromPowerPlant(household, powerPlant) {
    household.disconnect(powerPlant.disconectFromPowerPlant());
  }

  killPowerPlant(powerPlant) {

  }

  repairPowerPlant(powerPlant) {

  }

  householdHasEletricity(household) {
    return household.statusCheck();
  }
}

class Household {
  constructor() {
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = false;
  }

  connecting(connectStatus) {
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = connectStatus;
  }

  disconnect(disconectStatus) {
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = disconectStatus;
  }

  statusCheck() {
    return this.isConnectToPowerPlant;
  }
}

class PowerPlant {
  constructor() {
    this.listOfKilledPlants = [];
    this.isActive = true;
  }

  connectFromPowerPlant() {
    return true;
  }

  disconectFromPowerPlant() {
    return false;
  }
}

const assert = {
  equal: (a, b) => {
    if (a !== b) {
      return console.warn('test fail', a, b);
    }
    console.log('test ok');
  }
};

const world = new World();

const household1 = world.createHousehold();
const household2 = world.createHousehold();

const powerPlant1 = world.createPowerPlant();
const powerPlant2 = world.createPowerPlant();

world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household1, powerPlant1);
world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household1, powerPlant2);
world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household2, powerPlant2);

assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), true);
assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), true);

world.killPowerPlant(powerPlant2);
assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), true);
assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), false);

world.killPowerPlant(powerPlant1);
assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), false);
assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), false);
```

Comment: Приведите [mre], а не смешивайте в кучу всё

Comment: Доброй ночи ,скажите пожалуйста ,мне на учебе дали задание вот такого плана 

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-cori-qoyey?file=/src/index.js

И так как я в программировании новичек ,то могли бы подсказать ,как правильно было бы задать вопрос,или подскажите как правильно начать реализовывать задачу ,только задайте направление,буду очень благодарен за ответ,спасибо заранее!

Comment: Используйте [ask] и [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Ваша функция `killPowerPlant` ничего не делает.

Да и подсоединение дома к электростанции явно не делает то, что ожидается.

Comment: Увидел ,действительно вы правы ,могли бы подсказать ,как ее лучше реализовать эту функцию ,ткните хотя бы в нужную сторону.Еще раз спасибо ,за то что так поздно ответили!

Comment: @ИгорьАнтонов При такой логике ее нельзя реализовать. Надо переделать подсоединение к станции. По тестам похоже, что дом может быть подсоединен к нескольким станциям. Можно внутри станции завести список домов, а внутри дома - список станций. При отсоединении - удалять из этих списков соответствующие объекты.

Comment: @ИгорьАнтонов Другой вариант - соотношение домов и станций может храниться в объекте мира.

Comment: Я восхищаюсь вашим уровнем знаний,действительно в задании так и есть ,дом может питаться не только от станций ,но и от домов в  котором есть электричество вот :

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-cori-qoyey?file=/src/index.js

если переделывать логику,то в каком направлении?

Comment: @ИгорьАнтонов Так даже интереснее. Значит внутри дома должен быть список станций и список других домов. Надо принять меры от зацикливания ссылок домов друг на друга.